# Google Sheets SheetNames function for Visible Sheets Only

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a seperate sheet for each of our staff. I am wanting a dashboard page that will have a list of staff names when new sheets are added and also remove old staff when their sheet is hidden.

I am trying to figure out a way to run this code and only return the sheet names that aren't hidden, is this even possible? I have had a play around for the last few days but can't seem to get anything to work

```
    function SheetNames() {
    try {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
    var out = new Array( sheets.length+1 );
    //out[0] = [ "Name" , "gid" ];

    for (var i = 3 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ) out[i-6] = [sheets[i-1].getName()];
    return out
    }
    catch( err ) {
    return "#ERROR!" 
    }
    }
```

Comment: There is a isSheetHidden method for sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can use the method [isSheetHidden()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#issheethidden)

Sample:

```js
function SheetNames() {
  try {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var out =[];   
    for (var i = 3 ; i < sheets.length+1 ; i++ ){
      if(sheets[i-1].isSheetHidden()==false){
        out.push(sheets[i-1].getName());
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
  catch( err ) {
    return "#ERROR!"; 
  }
}
```